# wrapping enum class for python

Tags: pybind11

I am trying to wrap an enum class in a c++ header file for use in a python project.I have googled around and can not find out how to achieve this - is it supported?

```c
enum class scheme-type : std::uint8_t
{
  a=10;
  b=20;
};
```

How to convert the above code in python wrapper using pybind11

Comment: Please convert **at least** the `enum` part to a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently it remains elusive what your `scheme-type` means. Also, your question would be much improved using [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Yes, it is supported. You can look at https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/tests/test_enum.cpp for example code.